# Model component with self dependency

Tags: uml, modeling, diagrams

It would be my first system modelling so I am not really familiar with 
component diagrams. I know that I can use class instead of interface I just did not not attached to the component instead of the interface.

I have a task to model my web application's component.
[image]

It is(Orders) based on a web form, and to add(my add method) to the database it depends on if there exist entity with same value or not in the database. So the component is **depend on itself**.

How can I visualize this?

Update1:
I know that component diagram is a high level model but don't understand that if one component can dependent from one other, than is it possible to be dependent byself?
[image]

Update2:
Based on Ister answer i would like to ask if this model is properly show that the component is dependent of its (previous) instances?
[image]

Or this is does not necessarily  since it is a high level model and its obviously its dependent on its own class and its enough to visualize this in the activity diagramm?

Comment: I am not sure you're using the right kind of diagram for that. If you want to represent a chain of actions, use the sequence or state diagram. Components diagram are only to show high level components.

Comment: Walfrat thank you for your comment, help. I uploaded one more diagram to try to explain my doubt.

Comment: From what I saw in your comment in Ister's post, you want to modelize that you need to perform a check before adding ? This is not what components diagram are for. Use a sequence diagram in order to show the sequence of action performed for a use case. If you need to represent your order structured as a list chained, do it as class level, by adding a dependency to itself on the class and don't forget to put a name on the dependency (like "next", "previous"). Note however that usually we just use a linkedlist provided by our language/library instead of redoing it ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

Consider those two options:

1. Component uses internal functions to achieve its goal

Well, that's natural. That's happening for **all** components. So you don't depict that as a dependency. It's normal that multiple parts of the same components collaborate to achieve component's goal.

2. Multiple instances of the same component collaborate

It's a rare case. But imagine a bunch of robots that are able to communicate. With each other. Each a separate instance of the same component. I this case you may say that the component depends on itself and then you depict that on a diagram.

The case you describe seem to be option one to me. But as you can see option two while rare is also possible.

Comment: Ister thank you for your well detailed answer, the general case is that from each type of orders must only exist one. So before add new order its necessarily to check if it is already exist that type, if yes than refuse to add to the database else add to the database.

Comment: If you like my answer please consider upvoting or making it the chosen answer. So I guessed correctly, your case is the first one in my answer so there is no component to component dependency. The way component performs its work has nothing to do with dependency to itself. You might want to model internal behaviour of the component but it's done on different diagram, usually activity diagrams, sequence diagram, sometimes interaction diagram or others. I would probably go for a sequence diagram in this specific scenario.